# Post data on PostMan works, whereas on java doesn't work

Tags: java, http-post, postman, form-data

The URL I called,

```
 http://test.sample.in/Inquiry/B2B/secureService.action
```

I have added the value in form-data without any header field in Postman which works like i expected.

where as it doesn't work on Java Post method,

```
    HttpPost encRequest = new HttpPost(redirectUrl);
   try {
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("accessCode", accessCode));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("encRequest", encryptionData));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("merchantID", merchantID));
    encRequest.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,"UTF-8"));
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   client.execute(encRequest);
```

I dont know what did i wrong. Any Helps.

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

First instead of using yourself the apache.http package, I recommend you to use a easy and fast networking library and one of the easiest to implement one would be [**Volley**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhv8l9F44qo) developed by Google. It eases you the transmission of network data and has a lot of other benefits mainly :

- Ease of customization, for example, for retry and backoff.
- Cancellation request API. You can cancel a single request, or you can set blocks or scopes of requests to cancel
- Debugging and tracing tools.

Here's the official training on how to use Volley: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html